# Rounding to the nearest term in a geometric progression

Tags: sequences-and-series

Consider the following progression:

```
R(i) = 5*10^(i/30)
```

where *i* is ith number within the progression.

I would like to devise an equation that will round input value to the nearest number from this progression.

For example 5th, 6th, and 7th numbers in this progression are:

```
R(5) = 7.338996338
R(6) = 7.92446596231
R(7) = 8.55664152074
```

And the 'rounding' equation T(x) should produce:

```
T(7.45) = 7.338996338
T(8) = 7.92446596231 
T(8.424523535) = 8.55664152074
```

Can anyone point me at the right direction for solving this? Is there any general methods for such things?

**Important requirement**: I don't want to use lookup tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The general geometric sequence  looks like $x_n=aq^n$. What I propose will work, when $a>0$ and $q>0$, $q\neq1$.

Nominally the task is to given $x$, find the $n$ that minimizes $|x-x_n|$. As the level of Laphroaig has already gone down tonight a fair abit, I'm gonna first cheat a bit, and look for the best match in the logarithmic scale. In other words, I shall first minimize $|\log(x/x_n)|$. After all, if $x$ is very close $x_n$, then $x/x_n$ is very close to $1$, and its logarithm should thus be close to $0$.

The idea is that from the equation
$$
x=aq^n
$$
we can solve for $n$ by taking logs. First we get $\log x=\log a+n\cdot\log q$, and then we can solve
$$
n=\frac{\log x-\log a}{\log q}.
$$
The problem is, of course, that this formula won't usually spew out an integer.
So let's write $y=(\log x-\log a)/\log q$. In the logarithmic scale the best match would be to round $y$ to the nearest integer $n$, and output $x_n=aq^n$ as the answer.

In order to answer your original question we make the following observation. We can always squeeze $y$ between two consecutive integers like
$$
n\le y< n+1
$$
for some unique integer $n=\lfloor y\rfloor$. As we the sequence is always monotonous, we know that $x$ is between $x_n$ and $x_{n+1}$. If you can spare the clock cycles, you can then simply check which gives the smaller error: $|x_n-x|$ or $|x_{n+1}-x|$?

Comment: In your case $a=5$, and $q=10^{1/30}$. You get away with a bit simpler code by using base 10 logarithms. You will then know without further ado that $\log q=1/30$, so in your case
$$y=30(\log x-\log 5).$$

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x)$ be a monotonically strictly increasing function of x. (Like R is).

Now, what you want is have g(y), which does the following.

First, it takes the applies $f^{-1}$ to y, round either up or down, then apply f again.

So, what you want is $g=f([f^{-1}(y)])$.

Where $[]$ rounds up or down depending on which final result is closer to y.